# Синонимизировать [числа]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Надо бы синонимизировать метки [числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0) (240 вопросов) и [число](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be) (2 вопроса). Главная - [числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0).

Comment: Страница вопросов на мете так и пестрит "синонимизировать... синонимизировать..." :)

Comment: Обе метки - мета-метки, сжечь бы их.

Comment: @Зонтик почему "мета"?

Comment: Сама по себе метка [tag:числа] неконкретная.  Нужно что-то более конкретное вместо неё ставить: [tag:числа-с-плавающей-точкой], [tag:int],  [tag:арифметика] или [tag:длинная-арифметика]

Comment: @Зонтик а [tag:строки] корректная?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ да, конкретная.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 3 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 2 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 2 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'число': [число] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 242
tag remapping of [числа] and [число] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym число -> числа was approved!
```

Comment: Стоит ли создавать синонимы для таких расплывчатых меток? В программировании ведь все так или иначе про числа. Тем более, у них нет описания, и непонятно, к каким темам их стоит применять: к числовым типам данных, числовым литералам, математическим операциям с числами?

Comment: + если в одной из них только 2 вопроса, можно было просто вручную поправить. Сдается мне, надо как-то начинать тонко намекать участникам, что малозначимым меткам не нужны синонимы...

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight также в программировании всё про биты и байты. Но это не мешает и не должно мешать быть таким меткам. Про "поправить вручную" не понял.